# How to save only one/two object(s) from struct to realm in swift?

Tags: swift, struct, realm

Here's a struct. Only "qKey" and "done" need to be preserved.

```
struct Level {
    let lvlName: String
    let lvlAuthor: String
    let lvlNum: Int
    let lvlKey: [Int]
       var done: Bool = false  
       var qKey: [Int] = [] 
}
```

This is something like a levels library:

```
class LevelsLibrary {
var lvl = [
Level(
       lvlName: "",
       lvlAuthor: "",
       lvlNum: 1,
       lvlKey: []
     ),
...]
}
```

I don't even know where to start. I can add "done" and "qKey" in class and set them as `@objc dynamic ...` but then class is gonna be too large.

Comment: What do you mean "class is gonna be too large"? The class only has two properties.

Comment: At the moment, I do not know any other way to add levels to the "game" other than to do it manually. So when I add many new levels, the class gets too... yes, another word is needed - too long

Comment: I would suggest reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/) because it will help you understand the fundamentals of Realm. You may not need to use a struct at all, especially if you are going to store game data. You will be using Realm objects as they are managed (stored in Realm). Take a look at the guide, try writing some code using Realm and when you get stuck with a specific piece of code, post it and we'll take a look. Also, please be specific when asking questions - this one is unclear. See [Create a Minimal, Complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh - and a "class being too long" isn't a thing. A class, also known as a Realm Model in this case can contain an "infinite" number of properties and the number of classes is only limited by disk space. The only limit is the number of bytes a particular property can hold, which is 16Mb.